# Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to push to cloud functions for my iOS app.  I followed the Firebase does and installed node in my folder but now I'm getting this error trying to push it up

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'
```

UPDATES

Trying to get latest firebase-admin returns invalid

Running `npm uninstall firebase-admin`
and then running `npm install firebase-admin` puts out these errors...
[image]

[image]

Comment: In Windows reinstalling Node.js worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a similar issue in my project. I solved it by removing the node_modules folder with `rm -rf node_modules`, then in package.json changing manually the versions for both firebase-functions to 0.7.3 and fire-amin to 5.5.0. After that just run `npm install` again.